# Java SVNKit version exception

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I've got a small java app, that works with the svn via SVNKit. But when I try to work with my local copy, it throws out this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: The path 'D:\mainWorkspace\wowaProj' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
```

I have SVN version 1.7.8, already reinstalled it once, but still getting the same error. 
Any ideas, guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVNKit is a standalone Subversion library implementation. You need to upgrade that (not a reinstall of your svn client, but SVNKit itself) to match the other svn client(s) which may have touched the working copy.

Comment: All of the versions match each other.